# Como puedo guardar en formato double cada elemento de una estructura que adentro tiene variables syms

Tags: matlab

Tengo la siguiente estructura (.mat) que sale de resolver un sistema de ecuaciones

[image: E11, E12 ... etc es el resultado de cada variable que sale de resolver el sistema de ecuaciones]

Necesito convertir cada variable en un double. El problema es que el número de variables va aumentando porque el .mat se genera dentro de un for. Es decir, el número de variables y el número de ecuaciones aumenta con cada for, por ende, no puedo hacer double(S.E11) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `fieldnames(S)` para obtener los campos, para luego recorrer la estructura en un bucle usando `getfield`, convirtiendo cada elemento a tipo `double` y almacenándolos en otro vector, por ejemplo:

```
field = fieldnames(S);
dbl=[];
for i = 1:length(field)
    dbl(i,1)=double(getfield(S,field{i}));
end
```